# How to create TMenuItem in FMX with shortcut as number key or +/- key?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to replicate something similar to the Inkscape Zoom shortcuts shown below. Note that these Inkscape shortcuts work whether or not the number pad is used.

[image]

The first problem is that setting the shortcuts via the Object Inspector isn't possible, as there are no options for these keys on their own without modifier keys. I then tried setting the shortcuts at runtime as shown below. This shows the shortcut numbers in the menu, but the shortcuts don't work. I press the number key and nothing happens, whether or not the num pad is used (the menu items do work if I click them). The `+` and `-` shortcuts don't work, either.

Another problem is that the `-` shortcut is shown as `'-'` in the menu for some reason, and the `+` shortcut is shown as `'='` because it's the same key. I have also tried using `TextToShortcut()`, but no luck.

Is this possible in FMX, or will I have to resort to using the function keys? I'd prefer to have consistency with Inkscape. I could handle the key presses in the Form's `OnKeyDown` event, but then how would I show the shortcut keys in the menu correctly (right hand side of the menu item)?

```pascal
MenuItem1.ShortCut := vkEqual;
MenuItem2.ShortCut := vkMinus;
MenuItem3.ShortCut := vk1;
MenuItem4.ShortCut := vk2;
MenuItem5.ShortCut := vk5;
MenuItem6.ShortCut := vk3;
MenuItem7.ShortCut := vk4;
```

Comment: I think I've answered part of this myself. I can set the shortcut text in the menu item by using the tab character. MenuItem1.Text := MenuItem1.Text + #9 + '+'. I can then handle the shortcut execution in the FormKeyDown event. However, I'd still like to know if it's possible to set these shortcuts so that they work automatically.

Comment: Have you tried `vkAdd` for `+` and `vkSubtract` for `-`? See [Representing Keys and Shortcuts](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Representing_Keys_and_Shortcuts)

Comment: Yes, those represent the number pad keys, but they still don't work. I've now solved the issue as I described above. It seems like there's no alternative to handling the key events in FormKeyDown.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from source :

```
item1.ShortCut := 8299;
```

[image: You get efect like on the picture]

Becouse Shortcut of TmenuItem is of TShortCut and this is
TShortCut = Low(Word)..High(Word);

its simple sum of key and Fkey :

```
Shift - 8192 

Ctrl - 16384

Alt - 32768


So we have 8299 = 
"numpad +" = 107 +
Shift = 8192
```

For using "+" and "Numeric +", use Action connected to Menu item:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Action1.Caption := 'Click'+#9+'+';
  Action1.SecondaryShortCuts.Add('Shift+=');
  Action1.SecondaryShortCuts.Add('Num +');
end;
```

best regards
Moskw@

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want shift, just +.

Comment: item1.ShortCut := 107; or item1.ShortCut := vk_Add

Comment: That's what I had tried already, but the shortcut simply doesn't work. Anyway, I have solved this problem now by handling the key press in FormKeyDown.

Comment: It's working.  You need simple add item1.ShortCut := 107; in OnCreate() or in the place where/when its needed.
I post a answer with picture but it was deleted by moderator (why?).

Comment: I wanted the shortcut to work when using numbers or +/- from the Num pad OR the normal keyboard keys (not all laptop keyboards have a num pad). I don't think your answer works for both. I don't know why it was deleted though. I think the only solution is the way I've done it which is working fine.

Comment: As I wrote.You have everytj\hink in my answer. You should write "give me exacly solution" in question. Use action like below :

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Action1.Caption := 'Click'+#9+'+';
  Action1.SecondaryShortCuts.Add('Shift+=');
  Action1.SecondaryShortCuts.Add('Num +');
end;

I will edit my answer for that to see that beter